# has_and_belongs_to_many select first 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I want to select the first 7 elements of a habtm association.

I am creating a WordPress vulnerability database for an Open Source project (WPScan).

There are vulnerable WordPresses, Plugins and Themes.

So, a WordPress, a Plugin and a Theme may have many vulnerabilities and a vulnerability may have (affect) many WordPresses, Plugins and Themes.

What I want to do within a view is:

- display the first 7 vulnerabilities which affect WordPress.
- display the first 7 vulnerabilities which affect Plugins.
- display the first 7 vulnerabilities which affect Themes.

Here is the Vulnerability model:

```
class Vulnerability < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :plugins
  has_and_belongs_to_many :themes 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :wordpresses

  default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC'
end
```

Then each WordPress, Plugin and Theme model has a `has_and_belongs_to_many: vulnerabilities`. The join tables have all been created and populated.

I've tried many different things to access the data I need with no success.

EDIT ---

Example, non-working code:

```
<% @wordpresses.limit(7).each do |wordpress| %>
  <% vulnerability = @vulnerabilities.find(wordpress.vulnerability_ids).last %>
  <%= vulnerability.title %>
<% end %>
```

The above returns the error:

```
undefined method `vulnerability_ids' for #<Vulnerability:0x00000103152828>
```

EDIT ---

Here's another non-working example:

```
<%= Wordpress.all.vulnerabilities %>
```

The above returns the error:

```
undefined method `vulnerabilities' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Wordpress:0x0000010628d5c8>
```

Comment: You can make the following query: `Vulnerability.find_by(id: @wordpresses.limit(7).pluck(:vulnerability_id))`

Comment: Thanks! I got the following error from this code ```SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: vulnerability_id: SELECT  vulnerability_id FROM "wordpresses"  LIMIT 7``` but the example below seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :plugins, -> { order("created_at DESC").limit(50) }
```

Or if in older rails it'll be

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :plugins, :order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 7
```

Edit:

Ok so can't you do
Controller:

```
@wordpresses = Wordpress.order("created_at desc").limit(7)
```

View:

```
<% @wordpresses.each do |wordpress| %>
  <% wordpress.vulnerabilities.each do |vulnerability| %>
    <%= vulnerability.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I might not have explained well. I don't always just want the first 7 plugins, themes, wordpresses, but in this particular instance I do. I will sometimes need all of them. The trouble I'm having is selecting the first X wordpresses that have a vulnerability within the view or controller, if that is where it is most appropriate.

Comment: edited but I'm now a little confused as to what you're trying to do with your examples.  edited code will get the first 7 wordpresses then dump out all the vulnerabilities attached to them

Comment: Thank you very much! Your edit example worked! I have no idea why this did not work for me... would using @wordpresses = WordPress.all in the controller have made the difference?

Comment: Yes, because WordPress.all is loading an activerecord relation, with the individual wordpresses in.  It's the individual wordpresses that have the associated vulnerabilities.  I've not explained that very well but hopefully you get what I mean.